# When does a photon become part of a moving system?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, thought-experiment

I was wondering when a photon becomes part of a moving system.
Does it need to be generated inside e.g a moving train? Or can it be a photon generated out-side the train but reflected by mirrors that are attached to the train body?

Imagine the photon clock thought experiment. Would the photon clock running with a reflected photon have the same time as clock with a photon generated inside the train?

[image: side view of train and track]

Answer (score 2):

"Part of a system" is a question about how someone analyses something by drawing boxes around separate components, rather than about what is actually there.

You can draw a box around just the train, and then you have a moving system that is "open", that lets the photon in.   Or you can draw a box around everything, and then you have closed system with parts that aren't uniformly moving.

Both can be reasonable ways to analyze things, if you're careful.

Time dilation (and length contraction) isn't a property of a system.  It's a property of an observer's perspective on two "events".  These can be the reflection (absorption and reëmission) of a photon in a light clock, but where the photon came from truly doesn't matter. (Though arranging for a photon to be captured from outside a light clock and kept in the right path to remain in it is incredibly difficult.)

If it helps, think of the light as it's own "system", rather than as a part of either the train proper.  But the important bit is the events, and those will be the same whatever the photon source.

Comment: Indeed, but does the mirror, which is fixed to train, make the reflected photon part of the moving system?

Comment: @tt42: What's the actual question that you think knowing "whether it's part of the system" will help you with?

Comment: This helps with the question if the "reflected" photon will have time dilation for an observer in the moving system. (e.g if he uses this refected photon in his onboard photon clock.)

Comment: @tt42 It truly does *not* matter where the photons come from, they just have to be moving in the appropriate direction. They don't "know" they're in the train. For that matter, you don't even need the mirrors to be attached to the train: the train can be in a long tunnel with a mirrored floor and ceiling.

Comment: One wonders why the OP would ignore a perfectly fine answer and repeat the question.....

Comment: @tt42 :  Asking whether a photon will "have time dilation" is like asking whether that photon will have a degree from a top university.  Time dilation is a relationship between two frames, not a property of a particle.  It's just not the kind of thing that it would even make sense for a particle to "have".

Comment: Thanks for the 2nd part of the answer. Considering the reflection as "absorption+re-emission" answers my question on when the photon becomes part of the moving system.

Comment: @tt42 No. It makes *absolutely* no difference if a mirror is attached to the train or to the ground. The photon doesn't enter some magical "you are now part of the moving system" field inside the train.

Comment: @PM 2Ring: when the photon is absorbed by an atom of the mirror it becomes part of the moving system, as the atom of the mirror is part of this system. Next it is re-emitted as a source inside the moving system...nothing magical I would say...

Comment: @tt42 But you get *identical* results whether the mirrors are fixed to the train or to the ground.

Comment: @PM 2Ring: yes identical to a photon clock that is carried in the train, although the wavelength might be slightly shifted for the reflected photon

Comment: @PM 2Ring: yes the reflected photon (R) will indeed behave identical to a photon clock that is carried in the train. (Except that the wavelength would be slightly shifted as the atoms from the moving system perceive a wavelength contraction when they absorb the out-side photon before re-emitting it)   But not the same as the photon that is transmitted directly (T) into the moving system.

Comment: @tt42 No, there is no Doppler shift in the reflection from a transversely moving mirror. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203691/123208

Comment: @PM 2Ring: Yes, according to your reference. The Mirror in the example of this question is not a transverse moving mirror, but a 45 degree mirror. Hence there is a perpendicular component...

Comment: @tt42 Oh, ok. I was talking about a standard light clock. Your angled mirror will cause Doppler shift, and aberration.